# Neo4j: Get all relations within a set of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have the following query:

```
MATCH (d:Document)<-[o:OCCURS_IN]-(a:Alias)
WHERE LOWER(d.content) contains 'keyword'
WITH COUNT(o) as degree, a as a ORDER BY degree DESC LIMIT 20
MATCH (a)<-[:KNOWN_AS]-(ag:Agent)
RETURN ag;
```

I filter all Document nodes containing a keyword and get the top 20 Alias nodes ordered by how often they are connected to the Document nodes. After that all Agents connected to the Alias nodes are collected and returned.

This gives me a set of Agent nodes. In addition to this I want to get all relations within this set of Agent nodes. This means that the returning set of nodes should be the same. Only relations in between these nodes should be added.

How can I archieve this without an additional query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you'd get all the direct relationships *between* all the `Agent` nodes returned by your original query:

```
MATCH (d:Document)<-[o:OCCURS_IN]-(a:Alias)
WHERE LOWER(d.content) contains 'keyword'
WITH COUNT(o) as degree, a ORDER BY degree DESC LIMIT 20
MATCH (a)<-[:KNOWN_AS]-(ag:Agent)
WITH COLLECT(ag) AS ags
UNWIND ags AS ag1
UNIWND ags AS ag2
MATCH (ag1)-[r]->(ag2)
RETURN r;
```

Comment: Does this perform well? Seems like the unwinding could cause some performance issues

Answer (score 1):

Just continue your query :

```
MATCH (d:Document)<-[o:OCCURS_IN]-(a:Alias)
WHERE LOWER(d.content) contains 'keyword'
WITH COUNT(o) as degree, a as a ORDER BY degree DESC LIMIT 20
MATCH (a)<-[:KNOWN_AS]-(ag:Agent)
OPTIONAL MATCH (ag)-[r]-()
RETURN ag, collect(r) as relationships
```

Comment: `OPTIONAL MATCH (ag)-[r]-()` Isn't this matching the relations to all connected nodes? I only want the relations to nodes that are already within my previous result set.

Comment: this match all related to the Agent nodes

Comment: They only want relationships between the `:Agent` nodes bound to `ag`.